# How to translate pythonic double for loop to standard code?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have this chunk of pythonic code that I've been having trouble understanding:

```
paths = [[end]]
while paths and paths[0][0] != start:
    paths = [[parent] + path for path in paths for parent in childToParents[path[0]]]
```

where `childToParents` is:

```
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'cog': {'log', 'dog'},
                            'dog': {'dot'},
                            'dot': {'hot'},
                            'hit': None,
                            'hot': {'hit'},
                            'log': {'lot'},
                            'lot': {'hot'}})
```

`end` is `"cog"`, start is `"hit"`. The expected output of paths is:

```
[["hit","hot","lot","log","cog"],["hit","hot","dot","dog","cog"]]
```

I have tried multiple variations of a double `for` loop. One such attempt is:

```
    paths=[[end]]
    while paths and paths[0][0] != start:
        for i in xrange(len(paths)):
            for parent in childToParents[paths[i][0]]:
                paths[i] = [parent] + paths[i]
```

But this only gives me:

```
[["hit","hot","dot","dog","log","cog"]]
```

How can I translate the code to a standard double `for` loop?

Comment: Very generally speaking, there's no trivial way to turn an arbitrary while loop into a for loop. Most for loops have a definite end point, and many while loops never end.

Comment: I believe you can't. I mean, obviously you can replace any `while` with a `for`, just use `for _ in count(): if not <condition>: break` but this is just syntactic quibbling... In this specific case it seems like the code is doing something like visiting a graph or following a set of paths in a graph. You generally cannot predict how many iterations you'll do since it depends on the graph structure.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not concerned with the for loop on the outside. I'm concerned with the pythonic duoble for loop as stated in the post title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested `for` loop in the comprehension works left to right, so the rightmost loop is the *inner* loop, the left loop is the *outer*. For example —

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [8,9,0]

[(a1, b1) for a1 in a for b1 in b]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
l = []
for a1 in a:
    for b1 in b:
      l.append((a1, b1))
l
```

Both will output the following if run

```
[(1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 0), (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 0), (3, 8), (3, 9), (3, 0)]
```

For your example code —

```
paths = [[end]]
while paths and paths[0][0] != start:
    paths = [[parent] + path for path in paths for parent in childToParents[path[0]]]
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
paths = [[end]]
while paths and paths[0][0] != start:
    paths_, paths = paths, []
    for path in paths_:
        for parent in childToParents[path[0]]:
            paths.append([parent] + path)
paths
```

Note the `paths_, paths = paths, []` needed to preserve the contents of `paths` to iterate over while still resetting it for the subsequent loop. Running the above with your inputs gives me:

```
[['hit', 'hot', 'dot', 'dog', 'cog'], ['hit', 'hot', 'lot', 'log', 'cog']]
```

Comment: `paths.append([parent] + path])` -> `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Also, I think the OP wants to get rid of the `while` loop.

Comment: @martineau thanks, typo. I don't think he actually does, but it's not exactly clear.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say. +1 regardless.

Comment: @mfitzp Nope. Don't want to get rid of the while loop

Comment: @martineau haven't tested it. https://www.quora.com/I-am-too-impatient-What-should-I-do

Comment: @mfitzp If I try your solution, it seems that I just have paths as an empty list as my end result

Comment: @AlanH yeah, my bad. I was focused on the loop, didn't see the reset of `paths`. Have updated with working version — you need to preserve `paths` as it's being reset.